# C++ bool not being initialized

Tags: c++, while-loop, text-files

Bellow is a simple program that is suppose to check a certain text file to see if a word, in this case a name, is present in it.

I keep getting a pop up stating "The variable 'NamePresent' is being used without being initialized." Isn't NamePresent initialized as a bool?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream NameFile("Names.txt");   
    std::string Name;
    bool NamePresent;

    std::cin >> Name;

    while(NameFile >> Name)
    {
        if(NamePresent == true)
        {
            std::cout << "This works!" << std::endl;
        }
        if(NamePresent == false)
        {
            std::cout << "Nope!" << std::endl;
        }
    }

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is declared as a bool.  You still need to assign it a value of either true/false:

```
bool NamePresent = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

"Initialized" means initialized with a *value*.

```
bool NamePresent = false;
```

In your code above, it is *declared* as a `bool`, but not initialized. Also, no other statement in your code assigns a value to `NamePresent` (but presumably you're working on that).

Answer (score 2):

Any decent compiler would give us the warning if program tries to use the variable which is not initialized(***uninitialized)***.

> test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: test.cpp:15:9: warning:
>   ‘NamePresent’ may be used uninitialized in this function
>   [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
>            if(NamePresent == true)
>            ^

You should pay attention to compiler messages carefully.

Comment: I'll be more conscientious of that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There are 4 important moments in the life of a variable:

1. Declaration

In this step you inform the compiler about the variable type. This is required so that the compiler knows how to interpret the data in memory, for example.

2. Definition

This is the "birth" of the variable. If in the declaration you specified its name and type, here you instruct the compiler to allocate memory for it. Note that a statement such as `int a;` is both a declaration and a definition, as it introduces a new name (a) and allocates memory for an int variable.

3. Initialization

When a variable is defined, some memory is reserved for it. The initial value of the variable is the content of that memory, which can be anything (this is usually known as garbage). So you need to assign the first *useful* value to your variable. Of course, you can use it without initialize it to a value, but this *is* error prone, as you cannot rely on the value of that variable. The compiler knows this and gives you a warning. Note that you will get also warnings if you initialize a variable in a loop or a conditional branch, as the condition might not be true or the loop might not be executed.

4. Death

Although this point has no real use for your question, it is worth remembering. A variable *dies* when it goes out of scope (usually when the instruction block where it has been defined ends, if it is a local variable, and when the program ends if it is a global variable).